# Scala 2.10 reflection: Creating an Array from a type

Tags: scala, reflection, types, casting, scala-2.10

I'm having trouble digging through Scala's (somewhat sparse?) documentation on the new 2.10 release. I have a situation where I am reading data recursively from a source without type information. On the time of reading I know the expected type, so I can check whether that type aligns with the incoming data.

My problem is: When attempting to retrieve a collection object with type parameters (for instance an `Array[Int]`), how can I use the expected type to ensure that the read values are of the correct type?

So far I've fiddled around with code provided by the [Scala Api](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html#using_an_implicit_parameter_of_type___or_) that allows you to extract type-parameters. I also read about the [Class Tags](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag) and how they can be used to create Arrays. So my next thought was to 1) find the type parameter, 2) create an array from that type and 3) see if the read data fits without exceptions, like so:

```
val paramType = paramInfo[Array[X]]  // Step 1: Find the X type parameter
val array     = Array[paramType](size) // Step 2: Can't use TypeTags#Type as a normal Java type...
// Step 3: Feed data into the array and hope for the best
// Step 4: Profit!
```

Since the above `paramType` gives me the Type, it should be a simple matter of converting that type to a class tag. But the answer illudes me.

To be honest this solution seems a bit messy to me, but I haven't been able to figure out anything smarter. If there are alternative solutions I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify, my above example should demonstrate that I want to extract type X from Array[Int] (for example) and then make an instance of an array containing that particular type. Hope that made it clearer.

Edit: Perhaps further clarification is in order (did I really make it that unclear? :-) ). I want to read a collection from a data-source. And I want that collection to be typed with the correct, expected, type. So let's say I call the method `readData`. Since I know what type to expect I give it a type parameter of that expected type. As an example, let's say Array[Int]. It could be Array[String] or Iterable[Any] or simply Null or whatever. When the `readData` method is called, I would like to match the given, expected type (Array[Int]) to the type of the data read from the external source. If the found type is the same type - or a subtype - of the expected type we, can cast and return the data. If not, an exception is thrown, informing the user that the found data wasn't of the expected type. So to sum it up: How do I make a call to `readData[Array[Int]]` work?

Edit: I solved the issue by creating an Array[Any], retrieve the expected type (X above) and iterate the array to see if the elements are of the same type (or subtype) of X. If they are, we can safely cast to Array[X]. In the example below the expected type is represented by E. It's pretty hackish, I know, but again: I'd love to see alternatives...

```
// Matches if the type of o corresponds (<:<) to the type of x
def verifyType(o : Any, x : Type) : Boolean = { ... } 

// Get the type of the array parameter (X)
val tpe = reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[E] tpe match {  
  // The returned Type is not an instance of universe.Type - hence the cast              
  case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args.asInstanceOf[List[Type]] 
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find type parameters in type " + tpe)
} 

// Iterate the array and make sure the types match
val hasWrongType = array.exists(e => !verifyType(e, tpe))

if (hasWrongType) throw new Exception(...) // The types does not fit
else array.asInstanceOf[E] // We can safely cast
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need anything new in Scala 2.10 to do this, though instead of earlier versions' `ClassManifest` you use the replacement, `ClassTag`:

```
def makeArray[T : reflect.ClassTag](length: Int): Array[T] = {
  val tTag = implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[T]]
  tTag.newArray(length)
}
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> makeArray[String](5)
res0: Array[String] = Array(null, null, null, null, null)
```

With primitive types:

```
scala> makeArray[Int](5)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

**Edit**: Take two:

```
def makeArrayLike(a: Array[_], length: Int): Array[_] = {
  val cA = a.getClass
  val cC = cA.getComponentType
  java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(cC, length).asInstanceOf[Array[_]]
}
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> val ai1 = Array[Int](1, 2, 3)
ai1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> val as1 = Array[String]("one", "two", "three")
as1: Array[String] = Array(one, two, three)

scala> makeArrayLike(as1, 5)
res0: Array[_] = Array(null, null, null, null, null)

scala> makeArrayLike(ai1, 5)
res1: Array[_] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is the same possible with the type Array[Int]? So the type would be ``Array[Int]`` like so: ``makeArray[Array[Int]](5)``. I'm looking for a way to extract the type parameter and turn that into the array-type, like your type T above.

Comment: @JensEgholm: Yup. Primitive types work fine, too. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't have the type of the object to create an array of. I know that the type is Array[X], and I need to extract X and make an array of that given type (to do my example above - which might not be the best way).

Comment: Then my best recommendation is that you find a statically typed solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve. I added a solution, but it is statically vacuously typed...

Comment: Well.. It's almost there :-) I'm just wondering: Since it is technically possible to retrieve the type at runtime, it should be possible to create a typed array with that type, right?

Comment: Be very clear: Types really only exist during compilation. Classes are what you have at run-time. If you can get the compiler to provide you a `ClassTag` or `ClassManifest` throught the `implicit` mechanism, you get a richer representation of the Scala types, but if you have only a value of unknown type, you're only going to be able to get at its `Class`.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: Bad phrasing, sorry. I meant that since I already have the outer type, it should be possible to retrieve the inner type, as per your example above, correct?

Comment: @JesperNordenberg: I agree - I'd love to see alternatives. I fail to see alternatives on how to define collection-types of elements read from a source without types..

Comment: @JensEgholm: Again, you don't have the "outer" (array) type. You have only its class. They're just not the same thing. Although I said it already and Jesper seconded it (as a Scala programmer of his caliber surely would), you really should try to design a statically typed solution.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: I'm not really sure if we're talking past each other or I'm just dim witted. I don't have the option to force the external data to be statically typed. I've revised my description a bit, so hopefully that will be more specific. I realize that types only exist at compilation, but at the time of calling, I do have the class of the outer type. And that class knows the class of the inner type, right? Your revised example creates an array from a ``value`` (by reflecting its inner type) - I'd like to create an array from a ``type`` (that is, not a type, but a class) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the time to answer. I solved it by using case matches on the reflection type. I'm not thorougly happy but I'll close the answer. I think Jesper Nordenberg had a good point about bad design. :-)